# how to combine Stagger and timeline in GSAP

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

Trying to acheive cross fading slider as in  http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/#cfimg3 using GSAP, 
I am able to do the animation for one slide not able to do for other slides, basically difficult to combine timeline and stagger

Code pen:https://codepen.io/shmdhussain/pen/MvjEom`

```js
// instantiate TimelineMax
const tl = new TimelineMax({  repeat: -1 });

    tl.to('.test', 2, {opacity:1, scale:1, ease:  Power0.easeNone})
    .to('.test', 4, {scale:1.5,ease:  Power0.easeNone}, ) 
    .to('.test', 2, {opacity: 0, scale:1,scale:1,  ease:  Power0.easeNone});
```

```css
img{
/*   width:100%;
  height:100%; */
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

img:first-child{
  position:relative
}

div{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.test{
  //opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200" alt="">
<img class="test" src="https://www.skynewsarabia.com/web/images/2017/08/01/969105/400/200/1-969105.jpg" alt="bb">
<!-- <img class="test"  src="https://www.skynewsarabia.com/web/images/2017/08/01/969022/400/200/1-969022.jpg" alt="bb">
<img class="test" src="https://www.skynewsarabia.com/web/images/2017/07/31/968732/400/200/1-968732.JPG" alt="bb"></div> -->
```

`

Answer (score 2):

You could try the position parameter or a `stagger` method to create the overlap. Although based on your code it seems that the position parameter is a better alternative:

https://greensock.com/position-parameter

Finally, and my intent is not to discourage people for asking GSAP related questions here, you'll get a better and faster support in the GreenSock forums:

https://greensock.com/forums